# How can I insert special characters into a text file using Sed on Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, sed, replace

I want to replace the second line of a text file using sed command in a .bat script. I can do this without any special characters, for example:

```
sed -i 2s/.*/SUCCESS/ file.txt
```

However the text I want to insert is the following:

```
outfolder = "G:\Folder with Space and Quotes\"
```

If I use the command:

```
sed -i 2s/.*/outfolder = "G:\Folder with Space and Quotes\"/ file.txt
```

The result is an error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unterminated `s' command
```

I imagine it doesn't like the special characters? How can I fix this?

Comment: You're going to have to escape a bunch of different characters in that desired string (the space, backslash, and quote at the very least), but I'm not sure if the escape character here is ``\`` because of `sed` or if it's `^` because of batch.

Comment: Try `sed "s/^.*\"\([^\"]*\/g\/[^\"]*\)\"><div.*/\1/"`

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the command with double quotes, escape the backslashes and double quotes inside the command, and use

```sh
sed -i "2s/.*/outfolder = \"G:\\Folder with Space and Quotes\\\"/" file.txt
```

Or, you may also use

```sh
sed -i "2s/.*/outfolder = "^""G:\\Folder with Space and Quotes\\"^""/" file.txt
```

Note that I used double quotes for the sed command, and the literal `"` are escaped with `^` outside of quotes. Note you also need to double escape backslashes in the replacement part.

Comment: Thanks, the double quotes work.However I used backslashes instead of ^. 
`sed -i "2s/.*/outfolder = \"G:\\Folder with Space and Quotes\\\"/" file.txt`